# Database SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Need help with the project, using SQL Developer. I can't seem to get the program to retrieve information from the tables. The output shows 'N/A' instead of values.

```
DEFINE V_MESS = 'ORDER NOT FOUND!! Rerun the program!!!'
DEFINE V_PARTNUM = 'N/A'
DEFINE V_PARTDESCRIPTION = 'N/A'
DEFINE V_CURRQTY = 'N/A'
DEFINE V_SUPPCODE = 'N/A'
DEFINE V_SUPPNAME = 'N/A'
DEFINE V_ORDERED = 'N/A'
DEFINE V_RECEIVED = 'N/A'
DEFINE V_QTY = 'N/A'


ACCEPT V_ORDNUM NUMBER format 9999 PROMPT 'Enter Order Number to Receive      (format 9999): '
--input should be 1010

SET TERMOUT OFF
SPOOL \IS380\receive.sql

SELECT 'DEFINE V_MESS=' ||'''' || ORD_NUM || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
  'DEFINE V_PARTNUM =' || '''' || PART_NUM || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
  'DEFINE V_PARTDESCRIPTION = ' || '''' || PART_DESCRIPTION || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || 
  'DEFINE V_CURRQTY = ' || '''' || PART_QTYONHAND || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || 
  'DEFINE V_SUPPCODE =' || '''' || SUPPLIER_CODE || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
  'DEFINE V_SUPPNAME = ' || '''' || SUPPLIER_NAME || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
  'DEFINE V_ORDERED =' || '''' || ORD_DATE || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || 
  'DEFINE V_RECEIVED =' || '''' || ORD_RECDATE || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
  'DEFINE V_ORDERED =' || '''' || ORD_QTY || '''' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) ||
FROM PART P, SUPPLIER S, ORD O
WHERE O.SUPPLIER_CODE = S.SUPPLIER_CODE
AND O.PART_NUM = P.PART_NUM
AND O.ORD_NUM = &V_ORDNUM;

SPOOL OFF
PAUSE "Retrieving Customer Information.  Please press the enter key"
SET TERMOUT ON  
START SPOOL \IS380\RECEIVE.SQL

PROMPT SP2-0137: DEFINE requires a value following equal sign
PROMPT
PROMPT Order Found. Verify the following:
PROMPT

PROMPT Part Number               : &V_PARTNUM
PROMPT Part Description          : &V_PARTDESCRIPTION
PROMPT Current Inventory Quantity: &V_CURRQTY
PROMPT
PROMPT Supplier Code: &V_SUPPCODE
PROMPT Supplier Name: &V_SUPPNAME
PROMPT
PROMPT Date Ordered    : &V_ORDERED
PROMPT Date Received   : &V_RECEIVED
PROMPT Quantity Ordered: &V_QTY

PROMPT ** Again, verify order information:                                           **
PROMPT ** In case of discrepancy (Order not found, Wrong quantity, etc.)          **
PROMPT **     Press [CRTRL] [C] twice to ABORT                                    **
PAUSE  ** If correct, press [ENTER] to continue
```

Comment: Welcome! You should read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The title "Database SQL Developer" does not state the problem of your's.

Comment: You're doing this via SQL Developer or SQL plus?